# Comparing two lists and seeing if two elements are present in both but not in the same position

Tags: python, list

I need to find a way to say R and Y are in both lists but not in the right place

```
    a = ['R','G','Y','Y']
    b = ['Y','R','B','O']
```

Comment: So for your example lists the algorithm should return `False` because `'R' `and `'Y'` both appear at index 0? What should the algorithm output for `a = ['R', 'R', 'X']` and `b = ['Y', 'Z'. 'Y']` where `'R'` and `'Y'` appear paired and unpaired?

Comment: Please specify your needs further an provide some code

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: It should say that there are zero letters that are present in both.

Comment: What? Your response does make no sense at all.

Comment: What should the program do with a test case like `a, b = ['R', 'R', 'Y', 'B'], ['G', 'R', 'P', 'R']

Answer (score 0):

Rather simple really.

```
for index,val in enumerate(a):
  if val in b:
    if b[index]!= val:
      print "%s is in both a and b, but at different indices."%(val,)
```

This iterates through `a` and keeps track of its current index. It then checks that the value is in `b` (and, obviously, it's in `a`, also.) If it is, then it checks to see if the values of `a` and `b` are different at `index`. You can add variability to this by altering the conditionals.

For example, if you only want to find 'R' and 'Y' once, then you'd need to record them. Try:

```
dup_values = set()
for index,val in enumerate(a):
  if val in b:
    if b[index]!= val:
      if val not in dup_values:
        dup_values.add(val)
        print "%s is in both a and b, but at different indices."%(val,)
```